# Is it possible to sleep at Podgorica airport?

Tags: airports, sleeping, montenegro, podgorica

I will fly to Podgorica, Montenegro. My plane arrives about 23:30, so I would like to sleep at the airport until something like 06:00 and then go to the city.

Is it possible to sleep at the Podgorica airport?

Comment: I guess you could simply find a chair and sleep there. I've done this a lot while traveling. Not sure if this airport in particular has rules against it. Or maybe you want a bed. You should specify more what you mean by "sleep".

Comment: https://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/podgorica.htm

Comment: @lord2701 Good for you, but many smaller airports, and Podgorica is one of them, close completely at night. You will be thrown out and have no chance to 'simply find a chair'.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo that's why I said that i wasn't sure. ;)

Comment: @choster That should be an answer, not a comment

Comment: @PeterM No, OP should search the web before posting the question.

Comment: @choster That maybe true, but that doesn't change the fact that your comment is an answer and *not* a comment.

Comment: @PeterM Link-only answers are comments, not answers.

Comment: In an effort to raise our [Site's stats](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4627/2018-goal-answer-rate-to-100-rank-1st-currently-99-and-20th-398-unanswer?cb=1), I'll create an answer based on @choster comment, Ok?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this source](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/podgorica.htm), Podgorica is a very small airport, that closes at night, and it's not possible to stay inside overnight.

There is the [Aria hotel](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-s1-g304088-d2261070-Reviews-Hotel_Aria-Podgorica_Podgorica_Municipality.html) very close to the airport with a free roundtrip airport shuttle, if pre-booked.